# Use of unresolved identifier with an image view

Tags: swift, image

Im trying to make a pick selecter but I get Use unresolved identifier 'imageusr' . I tried changing the Target Membership and with that I get a lot more errors. imageusr.image = image ( here its where it shows the error )

```
Import UIkit class ViewController2: UIViewController {
 @IBOutlet weak var imageusr: UIImageView!
var imagepick = UIImagePickerController()


@IBAction func seleccionar(_ sender: Any) {
imagepick.sourceType = .photoLibrary
imagepick.allowsEditing = true
present(imagepick, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
imageusr.roundedImage()
    imagepick.delegate = (self as! UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
} here

enter extension  ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage{
         imageusr.image = image
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: You are writing extension inside the class scope, keep it out side the class.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's a code alignment issue, the `extension` should be declared outside of the `class`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageusr: UIImageView!
    var imagepick = UIImagePickerController()

@IBAction func seleccionar(_ sender: Any) {
    imagepick.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagepick.allowsEditing = true
    present(imagepick, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageusr.roundedImage()
    imagepick.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}


extension  ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage{
            imageusr.image = image
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and get this other error  'Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey' and keeps the Use  unresolved identifier